# Changing to custom order status programmatically in WooCommerce, order no longer shows in list but status updates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some code that I had been using for years on an older WooCommerce site. It creates a custom order status, and when I use this order status throughout the admin panel, it works fine (manually change the order status of an order).

However, now, with the newest version of WooCommerce (6.6.1) when I programmatically change the order status as such:

```
$order->update_status('order-status-x');
```

It changes the order status (when I go to edit the order, it has updated) but it does not show in the list on the order list page, nor does it increase the count.

Notes:

1. If I do this with a non-custom order status, it works fine.
2. If I do this manually with a custom order status, it works fine.

Please advise, as I cannot figure out what is happening. I have rechecked the custom order status generation code multiple times, and do not believe this is the issue. If you can reproduce, please advise.

```
function register_awaiting_shipment_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => 'Preparing Shipment',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Preparing Shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Preparing Shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_awaiting_shipment_order_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-shipment'] = 'Preparing Shipment';
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses' );
```

And then to update the order via AJAX:

```
        $order = new WC_Order($orderid);
        if (!$order) exit();

        $order->update_status('shipment');
```

As mentioned, the shipment status does update. However, for some reason it does not show up in the main order list, nor does it increment the number of orders under that order status.

Comment: _"I have rechecked the custom order status generation code.. if you can reproduce, please advise"_ - How can we reproduce the problem if your question does not contain [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
If this is a general problem, you should report this as a WooCommerce bug via the official channels. Since it seems more likely that it is your custom code..